# why my laravel project is slower on local network than shared host?

Tags: laravel, apache, vuejs2, network-programming, firewall

I have encountered the odd problem in my project, my project works very fine on the shared host based on the Cpanel. however, on the local network of the organization, it is very slow.
On the local network, the project installed on the virtual server with bellow configuration:

1. win server 2012 x64
2. ram 8 GB
3. 3 real core and 6 threads
4. wamp server 3.1.4

the project is based on the laravel 5.8 and vue.js, and PHP 7.2. all request is based on the restful API and Axios. It is worth mentioning that the project runs smoothly on the server localhost.
Please help me on this matter.

Comment: Try with command line

Comment: try what with the command line?  the request send and receive time is very slow on clients. I've tested it using postman

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this, in my case it is due to a lot of CDN usage. Happened to my office project. As an alternative, I think using webpack and reducing CDN is an option.

Sorry I don't have enough reputation yet to reply via comments